# Is "all but" really ambiguous?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I found two dictionary definitions for this phrase:

1. Everyone or everything except those mentioned. *All but the weakest plants survived the hot weather.*
2. Almost. *In some places, bus service has all but disappeared.*

However, how can one figure out what is meant in the following examples?

> Society is all but rude, to this delicious solitude.

Does that mean that Society is *almost* rude,  or Society is *anything except* rude?

> It is all but impossible.

Does that mean that *It is almost impossible* or *It is anything except impossible*?

> He was all but dead when we found him.

Was he *almost* dead, or *definitely not* dead?

Comment: [Referential](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9967/all-but-idiom-has-two-meanings)

Comment: The example "Society is all but rude" is from poetry of the mid 1600s. It shouldn't be used as an example of common patterns in modern English prose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick-and-dirty rule would be to say that "all but [noun phrase]" carries the first meaning while "all but [adjective or verb] carries the second.

And you cannot apply it to an adjective that is modifying a noun unless you put hyphens between the parts--including the adjective, like in this example:
"I saw his all-but-perfect face on posters all over town."

Since "the weakest plants" is a noun phrase, "all but the weakest plants" means "excluding the weakest plants. Because "rude" is an adjective, "all but rude" means a slightly weaker degree of rudeness. Because "ran" is a verb, "he all but ran" means he walked very, very fast.

Comment: If we say:"He was all but a dead man when we found him" it will mean "He was quite alive", won't it?

Comment: VERY interesting! I had considered the meaning of an instance to be contextual, but this "quick and dirty rule" does seem to work! I can't upvote, though, without validation.

Comment: @user1425 "he's all but a dead man" he's very much alive, "he's all but dead" he's hanging on the edge of his life

Answer (score -1):

Okay, here is how I interpret this structure. No particular rule, just use your common sense.

But has a meaning i.e. "Except" or "excluding".

**Usage 1:**

In your first example:

> All but the weakest plants survived the hot weather.

Simply, replace "but" with except. Now it stands as:

> All except the weakest plants survived the hot weather.

**Usage 2**

Now consider this excellent example, I saw somewhere.

> He is all but (.....*anything; take a few pennies for example*...) broke.

What does it mean? Substituting except for *but* once again, it means **Except (*a few pennies*), he lost everything.** Observe that, it does not mean, he lost everything. He has still left some pennies with him. So it is better to say **He almost lost everything**.

So in a nutshell,

## He is all but a few pennies broke.

=

### He has lost everything except a few pennies.

=

#### He has *almost* lost everything.

Now in the same way, if we apply the second rule to your second example, it becomes:

> In some places, bus service has all but disappeared

=

> Bus service has disappeared in some places, except a few buses.

=

> *Almost* every bus has disappeared except a few buses.

Now use these two logic accordingly in your different examples.

(Hint: "It is all but impossible. " and "He was all but dead when we found him." In both the cases the meaning is "almost". Try to solve how.)