# Opposing meanings of 'all but'?

Tags: difference

I abstract this broader question from [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/33870/8712). I know that as a preposition, [but](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/but#) = Except; apart from; other than. 
1. Do the following 2 definitions of [all but](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/all-but?q=all+but), contradict each other?
2. How do you determine/deduce the right meaning between <1> and <2>?

> <1>. Very nearly⁫     ⁫⁫⁫⁫⁫    ⁫⁫  ⁫⁫   <⁫2>. All except

**Update Oct 30 2014:** User StoneyB answered that **all but** 'embraces WHATEVER falls short of entirety'. But  WHATEVER implies every notch in his scale above  `forgotten` (in his pink box in quotations),
so does this extensiveness  contradict <1> (ie: very nearly),
and user Dan Bron's Oct 26 comment (ie: **all but** =  *just short of*) ?

I tried https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/10671/8712 and the following  on ELU but remain mystified:
[“to be all but X”](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/9337/50720) | [the 2 paras under 'She was all but killed by the assassin.'](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/14079/50720) | [“He all but [did something]”](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/33413/50720) | [“All but” idiom has two meanings?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/9971/50720) | [“All but convinced” as a way of saying that one is, in fact, convinced?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/51598/50720).

Comment: @LePress, that you? Both are perfectly correct, and no, they are not contradictory; those are two ways of expressing the idea that something is *just short of complete*.

Comment: @DanBron: Thanks, yes. Would you please explain if your comment consists with StoneyB's answer below? It states that **all but** `whatever falls short of entirety`, but how short can it be?

Comment: @Up, don't ask me to say why, but you want to construct that question as "*Is your answer **consistent with** ...*", not "*consists with*". In re: "how short": we're dealing with a figure of speech here, not a quantitative measurement, so "exactly how short" is, of course, unspecified. But the implication is often "*very short*", or, indeed, the minimum amount. But context will determine in specific cases.

Comment: @Up, if you like this concept, and want to upvote it, why not upvote and accept Stoney's answer? He's saying the same thing, with greater detail and better support.

Comment: @DanBron In fact, your answer differs from user StoneyB's? You wrote `the implication is often "very short"`, so you're referring to `forgotten by almost everybody` (StoneyB). Yet StoneyB says that *all but* includes every scale in his answer except the most extreme `forgotten`?  This broadness contradicts the ODO's definition `very nearly` above?

Comment: @Up, I think you're misinterpreting Stoney's answer. There is no contradiction in his answer and my comment (on this question about whether there's a contradiction between two meanings of an idiom :). Anyway, I think you've got your answer (meaning: you now know what the phrase "all but" means), whether or not you believe Stoney's write-up embodies it perfectly, so maybe that is enough to satisfy your need.

Comment: @up, Suggestion: reflect on what's puzzling you with the phrase, taking into account what you've learned in the course of asking this question. Line up all the ideas in your head, and take a good look at them. Look for any suspicious characters. Then, try to describe it. Put your puzzlement in words; the more specific, the better. The more anchored in ideas or text presented to you in this question or in other resources you've located, the better. Try to make the source of your confusion as sharp and clear as possible. Then update your question, and we'll take another shot at answering.

Comment: @Up, I see. I hadn't read your discussion with Stoney on his question before. Yes, ODO is correct, and "all but" indicates only the 2nd to last item on his scale and not the ones above it.  His use of "whatever" was less formal/literal/precise than you are crediting it with.

Comment: @DanBron Thank you effusively! Seeing as your comments differ from user StoneyB's answer, would you like to recast your comment as an answer now?

Comment: @Up, what I am saying is that my *comment doesn't differ* from Stoney's answer, only that you have taken the wrong gloss of *whatever* (in particular, over-formalizing it) and thereby created a conundrum for yourself. That said, I am quite interested at a meta-level why you are so enthusiastic about casting as much as possible as answers, even to the extent of specially requesting so in your profile? I mean, this is a great example: you now know, for sure, the answer to your question. Why does it matter to you whether I post it or leave it as a comment?

Comment: @DanBron Thank you again. Please don't be offended by my requests; I'll try to remember not to request this. The reason is that only an answer can allow me to conclude a question as answered, has larger font, can be edited, and much more easily referenced, thus my preference over comments.

Answer (score 3):

There's no contradiction here. Think of the adjective in *all but + any adjective* as occupying the last notch in an implicit scale:

> forgotten by nobody
>   forgotten by almost nobody
>   forgotten by some
>   forgotten by many
>   forgotten by most
>   forgotten by almost everybody
>   forgotten

*All but forgotten* is a sort of 'hedge' which excludes the last term. It thus signifies a reluctance to say that whatever-it-is is **entirely** forgotten, but embraces whatever falls short of entirety.

Comment: Thank you. Would you please elucidate `falls short of entirety`? How short can it be? Anything above and including `forgotten by almost everybody`? Yet I interpret user Dan Bron's comment to suggest just`forgotten by almost everybody`, but please advise if I erred.

Comment: @UpvoteLawArea51Proposal I'll leave it as is. *Whatever* is whatever.

Comment: Thank you again. I apologise for bothering you again, but would `whatever` (in your answer) contradict and exceed ODO's definition 1:  `very nearly`?

Comment: @UpvoteLawArea51Proposal Nope. *Very nearly* entails *not entirely*.

Comment: Thank you again. I agree with your last comment. Yet `whatever falls short of entirety` includes every scale in your answer except the most extreme `forgotten`, right? This broadness contradicts `very nearly`?

Comment: @UpvoteLawArea51Proposal I think you are taking this entirely too literally.

Comment: Thank you again. I apologise for bothering you again, but what did I read 'too literally'? My English is basic so I can't differentiate and am very confused now.

Answer (score 2):

"All but forgotten" -- forgotten by nearly everyone; on the brink of being forgotten.

"All but one" -- except for one.

You can determine the meaning by looking to see if the relevant word after "but" is a noun|pronoun or a past-participle.

```
Before the use of DDT was banned, birds of prey had all but *disappeared* from this area.

The megabat is extinct, all but a *few* extant *frugivores*.
```