# 'Even so, the ... incentives ... all but guarantee that accountants will fail ... needs.' - 2014 US

Tags: meaning-in-context

> [[Source:  Dec 13th 2014 | NEW YORK | *The Economist* print edition, About 45% down the page]](http://www.economist.com/news/briefing/21635978-some-13-years-after-enron-auditors-still-cant-stop-managers-cooking-books-time-some)
>
> Although auditors cannot hope to verify more than a tiny fraction of
>   the millions of transactions their clients conduct, in order to comply
>   with the standards they physically count inventories, match invoices
>   with shipments and bank statements, and consult experts on the
>   plausibility of management’s estimates. Most firms’ records are at
>   least tweaked during the process. And even though private businesses
>   do not have to undergo audits, most mid-size firms buy one anyway,
>   because banks rarely lend to unaudited borrowers. The recent spate of
>   frauds in China, where auditing practices are far laxer, shows that
>   markets are right to assign a premium to companies that receive a
>   Western accountant’s approval.
>
> Those conflicts of interest
>   **Even so, the misaligned incentives
>   built into auditing [all but](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/37733/8712) guarantee that accountants will [fall short
>   of](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fall-short-of?q=fall+short) investors’ needs.** The beneficiaries of the service—current and
>   prospective shareholders—pay for it indirectly or not at all, while
>   the purchasers buy it only because they are required to. As a result,
>   companies tend to select auditors who will provide a clean opinion as
>   cheaply and quickly as possible. Similarly, accountants who discover
>   irregularities may be better off asking management to make minor
>   adjustments, rather than blowing the whistle on a mis-statement that
>   could embroil their firm in costly litigation.

Maybe a problem involves my persisting dread with **all but**, but how do you analyse/decompose the bolded? I tried to rewrite by overlooking the ancillary phrases (What are better terms for them?) I write in regular style words unchanged from the original above, and italicise those that I changed.

1. Even so, the ... incentives ...  all ***except*** guarantee that accountants will fail ... needs.

2.  Even so, the ... incentives ...  ***does not*** guarantee that accountants will fail ... needs.

3.  Even so, the ... incentives ...  ***may allow*** that accountants will fail ... needs.

Comment: 4. None of the above.

Answer (score 2):

"*All but* guarantees that..." means "nearly ensures that...".  Not absolutely, but "damn close".

**The housing community's minimum age requirement of 55 all but guarantees that the neighborhood will be quiet.**